# how to open a file in a .jar through java

Tags: java, file, jar

I want to open a file in .jar application and I want to use java to do this. Explaining, for example I have the file SF_Antivalent.xml and I want to open it with uppaal.jar. How do I do this using Java. I've written the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
public class test7 {
public static void main(String[] args){


    Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
    String file="C:\\Users\\V\\Documents\\diplwmatiki\\SFBs\\SF_Antivalent.xml";
    Process p=rt("C:\\Windows\\System32\\java.exe", "-jar", "C:\\Users\\"
            + "V\\Documents\\uppaal-4.0.13-aca\\uppaal-4.0.13\\uppaal.jar" + file);
}
```

}

and I get this error: the method rt(String, String, String) is undefined for the type test.
Is there something to do?

Comment: Did you forget to `exec()`?

Comment: Is the Jar file in question within the applications classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is a little confusing, however, I believe you want to run some application and pass the XML file as a parameter to it...

The problem is, you're treating `rt` as a function/method, not an object.  `Runtime` has the an `exec` method used to execute external commands, for example...

```
Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
String file="C:\\Users\\V\\Documents\\diplwmatiki\\SFBs\\SF_Antivalent.xml";
Process p=rt.exec(new String[]{
    "C:\\Windows\\System32\\java.exe", 
    "-jar", 
    "C:\\Users\\V\\Documents\\uppaal-4.0.13-aca\\uppaal-4.0.13\\uppaal.jar", 
    file});
```

Also, each command or argument you want to send to this external process must be it's own element within the array you pass to this method

This means tha `"V\\Documents\\uppaal-4.0.13-aca\\uppaal-4.0.13\\uppaal.jar" + file` won't actually have the effect you think it will.

I'd also recommend that you use `ProcessBuilder` over `Runtime#exec`, but that's me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because rt is a Runtime object, not a method. To call a method of rt do this:

```
rt.someMethodName();
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code above you cannot get XML file, you're trying to execute something, instead of opening file inside JAR archive

Look into [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), this will give you possibility to load any file from JAR